# When does Angular 2 actually process and update the data binding?

Tags: angular

I found following two statements which looks confusing to me in the Angular 2 documentation.

1. Angular processes all data bindings once per JavaScript event cycle, from the root of the application component tree through all child components.
2. Angular updates the bindings (and therefore the screen) only if the app does something in response to asynchronous events, such as keystrokes.

For both of above statements to be valid, according to my understanding the definition of "processing the binding" and "updating the binding" should be different. Can someone please explain the actual difference?